# Report Viewer - Out Of Memory Exception

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer

i'v got a problem with the Report Viewer form .NET 2008. I'ave to get Some 100000 Records for my company for a year dump report.

The problem is i get the OutOfMemory Exception on the design of report.

Do you know how can i fix it?

I get only the column i need and i use a Dataset to display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to formulate an answer that could even remotely be considered helpful.  Surely you've already considered that the number of records might be the problem.  If it is a design-time issue then surely you've considered tweaking the report query temporarily so that it only returns a few records.  If it is a runtime issue then consider asking for a nice new machine with >= 8 Gigabytes of RAM and a 64-bit operating system.

Comment: Hi, i'm agree with but my company doesn't want to invest more in IT ^^
So, i've a question on that, this is not link to an overload of data, like Excel, with more that 65535 records?

Comment: there is no record limit -- you've just run out of memory.  as nobugz said try returning fewer rows during design, or cut out some unneeded columns in the query.